# Braintree Drop-in container in Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, braintree

I'm trying to integrate a Braintree Payments drop-in into an Ionic mobile app. Based on the Braintree documentation and some code examples i was able to find online, the following code is what I've managed to come up with so far but it doesn't seem to work:

controller.js

```
.controller('CheckoutForm', function($scope, $window) {
  $scope.clientToken = "<token generated by the server>"

  $scope.renderCheckout = function() {
    braintree.setup($scope.clientToken, "dropin", {
      container: "payment-form"
      });
  }
})
```

template.html

```
<div>
  Payment details:
  <form id="checkout">
    <div id="payment-form" onLoad="renderCheckout()"></div>
  </form>
</div>
```

I also included the following line in the index.html:

```
<script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/js/braintree-2.23.0.min.js"></script>
```

I'm quite new to Ionic and HTML5/JS development in general so any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forget about the onload function. Just do this in your controller.

```
var clientToken = "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";

// Client token above is just for testing and provided by Braintree for testing purposes

braintree.setup(clientToken, "dropin", {
  container: "payment-form"
});
```

Then in your html:

```
<form id="checkout">
  <div id="payment-form"></div>
</form>
```

For mobile remember to add proper Content security policy and whitelists with the cordova-whitelist-plugin.

Documentation for CSP: https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/client-reference/javascript/v2/best-practices#using-braintree.js-with-a-content-security-policy

Documentation for Cordova whitelist plugin:
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/appdev/whitelist/index.html

Comment: Thank you for the cordova whitelist plugin. Will this be fine to use with an imported module of braintree drop-in or is this to be used strictly with cordova braintree plugin?

Answer (score 2):

What 'thepio' suggested is for testing only. But proper way might be to generate the Client Token on you server. Then your Ionic app will POST and get the Client Token from your server. And then once payment nonce is generated, you can POST your payment data to your server to process the payment.

Check this sample implementation.
https://github.com/demianborba/braintree-cordova-angular-node

Comment: I think the question asker is aware of that since he/she wrote `$scope.clientToken = "<token generated by the server>"` in his question. And in my answer I just clarified that the token in my answer is just for testing purposes :)

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Yes, I'm generating the token on my server and that's where the mobile app is requesting it from.